# I can't get the percentage

Tags: cognos

I need a crosstab or list.
X is defined as a constant for every user.
(case USER_ID
WHEN 1 THEN 116049
WHEN 2 THEN 37601
END).
Aggregate function and Rollup Aggregate Function:
X - MINIMUM,AUTOMATIC,
Y - TOTAL,AUTOMATIC,
Y/X - CALCULATED,AUTOMATIC
.

EXPECTATION
_____________________________________________
USER    | X        | Y       |  % (100*Y/X)
_____________________________________________
USER1  |  116049  |  51438  |  44
USER2  |  37601   |  17347  |  46
TOTAL  |  153650  |  68785  |  **45    Y/X**

---

REALITY
_____________________________________________
USER    | X        | Y       |  % (100*Y/X)
_____________________________________________
USER1  |  116049  |  51438  |  44
USER2  |  37601   |  17347  |  46
TOTAL  |  153650  |  68785  |  **10270 Y/X**

---

Percentage expression is "ROUND(100*[Q].[Y]/[Q].[X];0)".
I chose "automatic summary".
TOTAL percentage isn't correct.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks.